# How to work with ROS in new hardware platform?

Tags: ros, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi~ all.

I am a little familiar with ROS and bundle packages but
I have no idea with **"How to port or install ROS into new robot"**

Our lab has Darwin-Op robot and trying to use in ROS framework.
I checked myself in ROS wiki that PR2, Nao and several other platforms are supported but Darwin-Op is not mentioned.

And I cannot find any guide for this (How to port ROS into other robots) in ROS.org.

Do you have any idea or information with this problem?

Thank you for reading.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44087/how-to-work-with-ros-in-new-hardware-platform?/) by [nzer0](https://answers.ros.org/users/3225/nzer0/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2012-09-18

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Loy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1830/loy/) on 2012-09-19**:
However you do it, if such a guide does not exist, it would be very useful to document your process in some sort of wiki so a guide can be created.

**Comment by [nzer0](https://answers.ros.org/users/3225/nzer0/) on 2012-09-23**:
I got an email from a researcher and got this good implementation for Darwin (I've not yet tried though): http://wiki.iri.upc.edu/index.php/Darwin_installation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The first steps would obviously be to google/search the wiki if someone has done this already. At least some parts are probably already done, for example laser or camera drivers. It looks like you already did that, so you'll need to port the robot on your own. Unfortunately, I am not aware of a generic "porting robots to ROS" guide. Here are (some) of the steps that you'll need to do for that, assuming that you not only want to use ROS for communication, but also want to utilize other packages like, e.g. navigation.

- Setup a [URDF](http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf) description for your robot. You should have understood [tf](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf) and read the following REPS:

  - [REP 103](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html)
  - [REP 105](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html)
- Port your drivers to ROS, here it is very advisable to look for common ROS messages, that obvisouly depend on the hardware. Some examples:

  - geometry_msgs/Twist for controlling base movements
  - sensor_msgs/JointState for publishing joint states (angles) of articulated robots
  - sensor_msgs/LaserScan for lasers
- Setup launch files that bring up your robot

This should leave you with a robot that runs, can be teleoperated, and where you can visualize everything in rviz.

More things to look into are [diagnostics](http://www.ros.org/wiki/diagnostics), navigation, arm navigation.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2012-09-20**:
That would be a good start for a guide in the wiki which should be made, as there have been similar questions. E.g. http://answers.ros.org/question/11833/i-have-a-mobile-robot-that-isnt-currently-supported-by-ros-how-should-i-structure-the-driver-nodes-to-expose-my-robots-integrated-sensors-and/

**Comment by [nzer0](https://answers.ros.org/users/3225/nzer0/) on 2012-09-23**:
Thanks a lot for kind instructions

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since Darwin OP is built from Dynamixel motors it might be worth looking at the [dynamixel_motor](http://ros.org/wiki/dynamixel_motor) stack. Once you have a URDF description of your robot you can define joint controllers  (motor ids, min/max limits, baud rates, etc.) for the dynamixel_motor stack that will give you ability to control and monitor the state of single joints through ROS topics.

---

Originally posted by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) with karma: 2121 on 2012-09-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nzer0](https://answers.ros.org/users/3225/nzer0/) on 2012-09-23**:
Thanks for information about Dynamixel stack

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know that the initial question is broader than the specific stated goal of `using the Darwin-OP with ROS`, but I think that the [existing package](http://ros.org/wiki/iri_darwin_robot) for this robot would be an excellent starting point for the OP.

This package could be used as an aide to develop the generic how-to (and to learn more about ROS).

To be clear, I haven't used the package personally. From everything I've read and [seen](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=07xahYakyBY)), there already is a [urdf](https://devel.iri.upc.edu/pub/labrobotica/ros/iri-ros-pkg/stacks/iri_darwin/trunk/iri_darwin_robot/models/darwin.urdf) file. I also gather that simulations are also provided via webots.

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) with karma: 2022 on 2012-09-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1